# websocket for binary transfer of data & decode

Tags: html, standards, w3c, websocket

I was reading through the specification and many examples about usage of websockets. Almost all of them talk about UTF-8 or ascii message transfer using websockets.

The latest Hybi websocket spec requested support for binary transfer. [REQ 6 in hybi spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-hybi-websocket-requirements-01)

Also i read somewhere that chrome supports hybi. But latest release Chrome 7.0 works only when [draft-hixie](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hixie-thewebsocketprotocol-75) is selected in pywebsocket config.

Does any browser have support for hybi spec? Even if it is dev, its ok.

Comment: I guess you'll know this by now, but as a general update to everyone - Chrome Canary now supports this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It may be a while before non-UTF-8 (i.e. binary) encoding is supported in WebSockets.

I suggest using base64 encode/decode on the client and server. All browsers with WebSockets support have window.atob (base64 decode) and window.btoa (base64 encode). Most languages you might write a WebSockets server in have base64 libraries (i.e. base64 module in python).

If you are wanting to transfer binary data you might be interesting in wsproxy included with [noVNC](http://github.com/kanaka/noVNC/) which is a web based VNC client. wsproxy (there is a C and python version) is a WebSockets to generic TCP sockets proxy. It base64 encodes/decodes all traffic to/from the browser. You can use it to connect from a WebSockets capable browser to any type of TCP port.

Note, noVNC has a Javascript implementation of base64 encode/decode because belief it or not, the Javascript version is slightly faster than atob/btoa.

Disclaimer: I created noVNC.

Comment: Update: the IETF-07 draft of the WebSockets protocol is in last call and has binary frame support. Here is a bug with discussion of API changes to add binary support: http://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=12102