# What Connection is this?

Tags: java, websocket, jetty, embedded-jetty

So I'm following tutorial of [Face detection using HTML5, javascript, webrtc, websockets, Jetty and OpenCV](http://www.smartjava.org/content/face-detection-using-html5-javascript-webrtc-websockets-jetty-and-javacvopencv). Not exactly like that, but more or less like that (Like, I don't use the face detection thingy). I use Eclipse to implement it.

There's these parts (I simplified it)

```
private Connection connection;

public void onOpen(Connection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
        this.connection.setMaxBinaryMessageSize(1024 * 512);
    }

public void onMessage(byte[] data, int offset, int length) {
    try {
        this.connection.sendMessage(data, 0, data.length);
    } catch (IOException e) { }
}
```

and the specific line that's confusing me is

`this.connection.sendMessage(result, 0, result.length);`

what is the `Connection` that's being used here? When I use Ctrl+Shift+O of Eclipse, from the lib I had, Eclipse offer these

1. `org.eclipse.jetty.io.Connection`
2. `org.eclipse.jetty.client.api.Connection`
3. `java.sql.Connection`

but none of the Connection it gave have that `sendMessage` method. I've tried searching the net, but the tutorials I've found that used the same line, also didn't tell anything about it.

What is that Connection? Is there from any lib I haven't had yet?

And there's [this javadoc page of that seems to explain this class](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/7.6.14.v20131031/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/WebSocket.Connection.html), and it does have the same method with same params, but I still don't understand. Seems that it comes with Jetty, but which jar? I used Jetty 9.x though...

Thank you very much.

Comment: Looks like Play2 classes

Comment: I've edited it, with link to the javadoc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be from the org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.WebSocket package.

You can find the JAR here:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-websocket/8.1.0.RC5